# child component of next-themes in nextjs13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

i used Next-theme to apply dark mode in nextjs 13.
If you look at the github of next-theme

```
'use client'

import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes'

export function Providers({ children }) {
  return <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
}
```

```
// app/layout.jsx

import { Providers } from './providers'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

you can see like this.
so I got a question is this.
If I apply dark mode, will all child components become client components??
why i think like that because it is the Providers is 'use client'(client component) that surrounds {children}.
Please reply T.T....
Thank you.

i write all of my thinking

Answer (score 0):

[As per Next.js doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#supported-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props),

> You can pass Server Components as a prop to a Client Component.

What you are doing is, importing a client component (`<Providers>`) in a server component (`<Layout>`) and passing `children` as prop. This won't make the whole website client side rendered!

> `<Providers>` doesn't know that children will eventually be filled in by the result of a Server Component.

So, you can wrap your whole website with `<Providers>` but `children` will be server side rendered and eventually be filled in.

The doc also mentions the following possible pattern,

> In a parent Server Component, you can import both the `<ClientComponent>` and `<ServerComponent>` and pass `<ServerComponent>` as a child of `<ClientComponent>`

```
// This pattern works:
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
// Client Component.
import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  )
}
```

Just in case there's any confusion, you **can't directly import** a server component in a client component. The following code will throw error,

```
'use client'
 
// You cannot import a Server Component into a Client Component.
import ServerComponent from './Server-Component'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
 
      <ServerComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```